# C# VSTO - Modify MailItem in ItemSend event handler?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

Having an issue modifying a MailItem in the ItemSend event handler before this MailItem is actually sent.  The MailItem modified with DeferredDeliveryTime will sit in the Outbox and never get sent. Same result if MailItem.Save() is called or not.  I am assuming now that successfully modifying a MailItem in this event handler necessitates specific steps or approach. Any guidance will be appreciated.

```
private void ItemSendEventHandler(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
{
  if (Item is MailItem)
  {
    try
    {
      MailItem mailItem = Item as MailItem;

      if (someCondition == true) 
      {
        // Defer by 60 seconds (will be rounded to the nearest minute)
        mailItem.DeferredDeliveryTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60);
        mailItem.Save();
      }
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
      LogFile.LogException(ex);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you then look at the Outbox folder? Keep in mind that touching an item being submitted with OOM or Outlook UI aborts the submission process

Comment: Yes, looking at the Outbox folder after having placed a break point in ItemSend to verify that the code is being executed without errors.  I suspect that touching an item at that stage (ItemSend) is probably aborting the submission.  Any suggestion on how to get around this?

Comment: ItemsSend is called before the message is actually submitted (hence the Cancel parameter). Do you have the reading pane on in the Outbox?

Comment: Reading pane is off for the Outbox folder.

Comment: Is message shown italicized in the Outbox folder?

Comment: Doesn't appear to ever be italicized - and if it is, it would be for a visually imperceptible time

Comment: And if you modify any other property (such as Subject), does it get italicized?

Comment: Changing the Subject doesn't suspend the send process, message gets sent and delivered with the modified subject        

( mailItem.Subject = "Hello - test";
mailItem.Save(); )    -- Seems to be an issue specific to setting the delay delivery property.  Puzzling.