# VSTO Outlook: identify object

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

How can I get member variable class(int) from object Item in the below function?
I can see it in Visual Studio debugger dynamic view. but not sure how could I access this programmatically.

```
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.ItemSend += new Outlook.ApplicationEvents_11_ItemSendEventHandler(Application_ItemSend);
```

```
void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
```

I want to use something like
(int)Item.class
So I can see Item's class such as mailitem, taskitem or meetingitem. and process accordingly.

Comment: You can check the type of Item with the `is` operator and then cast Item to that type, for example as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65148209)

Comment: I found (dynamic)Item.Class to retrieve the value. Does this incur any error? Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard .net ways of checking the item type at runtime, for example:

```
            if (Item is Outlook.MailItem)
            {
                Outlook.MailItem mailItem =
                    (Item as Outlook.MailItem);
                itemMessage = "The item is an e-mail message." +
                    " The subject is " + mailItem.Subject + ".";
                mailItem.Display(false);
            }
            else if (Item is Outlook.ContactItem)
            {
                Outlook.ContactItem contactItem =
                    (Item as Outlook.ContactItem);
                itemMessage = "The item is a contact." +
                    " The full name is " + contactItem.Subject + ".";
                contactItem.Display(false);
            }
            else if (Item is Outlook.AppointmentItem)
            {
                Outlook.AppointmentItem apptItem =
                    (Item as Outlook.AppointmentItem);
                itemMessage = "The item is an appointment." +
                    " The subject is " + apptItem.Subject + ".";
            }
            else if (Item is Outlook.TaskItem)
            {
                Outlook.TaskItem taskItem =
                    (Item as Outlook.TaskItem);
                itemMessage = "The item is a task. The body is "
                    + taskItem.Body + ".";
            }
            else if (Item is Outlook.MeetingItem)
            {
                Outlook.MeetingItem meetingItem =
                    (Item as Outlook.MeetingItem);
                itemMessage = "The item is a meeting item. " +
                     "The subject is " + meetingItem.Subject + ".";
            }
```

See [How to: Programmatically determine the current Outlook item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-determine-the-current-outlook-item?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp) for more information.

Comment: I want to catch every type so wondering what's the shortest way.
Otherwise I need to pick every possible type from
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.olobjectclass?view=outlook-pia
and create statements.
Thank you,

Comment: There is a definitive set of items in Outlook, not so long. This is the most efficient and proper way of identifying an object at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Either use the `Class` property (it is exposed by all OOM objects) - it will be 43 (`OlObjectClass.olMail`) for the `MailItem` objects, or use "is" and/or "as" operators.

Comment: When meeting item/task items are sent, the type would be different so if I want to check some property of the item, such as recipient or attachment, I need proper type class to retrieve those.  I think so far int type = (dynamic)Item.Class and do switch case may be the best way to catch.

Comment: Yes, the Class property is the way to go. Or cast to `MailItem` and check that the resulting object is not null. Either way.

Comment: Accessing the `Class` property requires reflection or casting the object anyway. If you would like to get an efficient code you need to go with `as` or `is` operators in C#.

Comment: Both methods are similar performance wise - reflection requires GetIdsOfNames / Invoke calls, "as" / "is" require a QueryInterface call.

Comment: I've read somewhere statements that `as`/`is` is much faster than just pure reflection used in the code.

Comment: Both would be in the sub-microsecond range. When used in the end user-driven `Application.ItemSend` event, there would won't be any perceptible performance loss or gain either way.